# adding command line arguments to multiple scripts in python

Tags: python, refactoring, command-line-arguments, python-decorators

I have a use case where I have a main python script with many command line arguments, I need to break it's functionality into multiple smaller scripts, a few command-line arguments will be common to more than one smaller scripts. I want to reduce code duplicacy. I tried to use decorators to register each argument to one or more scripts, but am not able to get around an error. Another caveat I have is I want to set default values for shared argument according to which script is being run. This is what I have currently

argument_parser.py

```
import argparse
import functools
import itertools

from scripts import Scripts
from collections import defaultdict

_args_register = defaultdict(list)

def argument(scope):
    """
    Decorator to add argument to argument registry

    :param scope: The module name to register current argument function to can also be a list of modules
    :return: The decorated function after after adding it to registry
    """

    def register(func):
        if isinstance(scope, Scripts):
            _args_register[scope].append(func)
        elif isinstance(scope, list) and Scripts.ALL in scope:
            _args_register[Scripts.ALL].append(func)
        else:
            for module in scope:
                _args_register[module].append(func)

        return func

    return register


class ArgumentHandler:

    def __init__(self, script, parser=None):
        self._parser = parser or argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
        assert script in Scripts
        self._script = script

    @argument(scope=Scripts.ALL)
    def common_arg(self):
        self._parser.add_arg("--common-arg",
                             default=self._script,
                             help="An arg common to all scripts")

    @argument(scope=[Scripts.TRAIN, Scripts.TEST])
    def train_test_arg(self):
        self._parser.add_arg("--train-test-arg",
                             default=self._script,
                             help=f"An arg common to train-test scripts added in argument handler"
                             )

    def parse_args(self):
        for argument in itertools.chain(_args_register[Scripts.ALL],
                                        _args_register[self._script]):
            argument()

        _args = self._parser.parse_args()
        return _args
```

One of the smaller scripts train.py

```
"""
A Train script to abstract away training tasks
"""

import argparse

from argument_parser import ArgumentHandler
from scripts import Scripts

current = Scripts.TRAIN

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)


def get_args() -> argparse.Namespace:
    parser.add_argument('--train-arg',
                        default='blah',
                        help='a train argumrnt set in the train script')
    args_handler = ArgumentHandler(parser=parser, script=current)
    return args_handler.parse_args()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_args())
```

When I run train.py I get the following error

```
File "../argument_parser.py", line 68, in parse_args
    argument()
TypeError: common_arg() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think this is because decorators are run at import time, but am not sure, is there any work around this? or any other better way to reduce code duplicacy? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What's happening is that the decorator `argument`'s `register` inner function took in the unbound function `common_args`, and then it was then invoked directly in the for loop by `argument()`, and since it's an unbound function, the `self` implicit argument will not be passed.  You may workaround this issue by calling `argument(self)` instead.

Comment: This works! Thank you.